# 500 error with MySQLdb Python when pulling data from tables

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, sha256

I am unsure why this code is giving me a 500 error on my web app with Flask, can someone tell me where my logic is wrong? I have a feeling it has to do with the sha256_crypt.verify() functions, but unsure how to get around this. Just trying to pull all the data on a user from my tables and put it into the session variable. Let me know, thanks!

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login_page():
    error = ''
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        if request.method == "POST":
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(request.form['email']),))
            pdata = c.fetchone()[3]

            if sha256_crypt.verify(request.form['password'], pdata):
                #get info from clients table
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (email,))
                clients_results = fetchall()
                clientcid = clients_results[0]
                #get info from cpersonals table
                c.execute("SELECT * FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
                cpersonals_results = fetchall()

                conn.commit()
                c.close()
                conn.close()


                session['logged_in'] = 'client'
                session['clientcid'] = clientcid
                session['email'] = email
                session['phone'] = clients_results[1]
                session['rating'] = clients_results[4]
                session['first_name'] = cpersonals_results[1]
                session['last_name'] = cpersonals_results[2]
                session['address'] = cpersonals_results[3]
                session['czip'] = cpersonals_results[4]
                session['reg_date'] = cpersonals_results[5]
                flash("You are now logged in.")
                return redirect(url_for("ask"))

            else:
                error = "Invalid credentials, try again."

        return render_template("login.html", error = error)

    except Exception as e:
        #flash(e)
        error = "Invalid credentials, try again."
        return render_template("login.html", error = error)
```

Log: (sorry not sure how to post this properly)

```
   .991239 mod_wsgi (pid=5585): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
 .948625   mod_wsgi (pid=5585): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
 .948649   Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
 .948670     File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
 .948744       from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
 .948857     File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 270, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
 .948869       conn.commit(), referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
 .948873                   ^, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
 .948877   IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
06.003866   mod_wsgi (pid=5586): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
06.003919   mod_wsgi (pid=5586): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
06.003942   Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
06.003964     File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
06.004030       from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
06.004076     File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 270, referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
06.004083       conn.commit(), referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
06.004087                   ^, referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
06.004090   IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level, referer: http://138.197.210.172/account/
09.513219   mod_wsgi (pid=5585): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://138.197.210.172/
09.513258   mod_wsgi (pid=5585): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://138.197.210.172/
09.513280   Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
09.513301     File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
09.513335       from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
09.513357   ImportError: cannot import name app, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
09.550576   mod_wsgi (pid=5586): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
09.550615   mod_wsgi (pid=5586): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
09.550639   Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
09.550661     File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
09.550697       from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
09.550718   ImportError: cannot import name app, referer: http://138.197.210.172/view_unanswered/
12.922623  mod_wsgi (pid=5585): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.922697  mod_wsgi (pid=5585): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.922743  Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.922768    File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.922807      from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.922838  ImportError: cannot import name app, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.955475   mod_wsgi (pid=5586): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.955537   mod_wsgi (pid=5586): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.955561   Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.955584     File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.955620       from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
12.955641   ImportError: cannot import name app, referer: http://138.197.210.172/
```

Comment: Paste the exception from your logs.

Comment: Done, sorry I don't know if thats the right way to post an error log lol

Comment: You haven't setup mod_wsgi configuration to tell Python where your project code is located. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/

Comment: Also read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html as Flask docs don't actually describe best practice for virtual environment setup.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton hmmm well I remember setting up wsgi early on on my server and my program runs if I just dont put the `fetchall()` function inside the `sha256 if` statement, so I am not sure if it's the wsgi issue, but I can investigate further!

Comment: I wouldn't even get that far because of the error ``ImportError: cannot import name app``. That generally indicates can't find the application package properly.

Comment: Sorry I am unfamiliar with wsgi, but I looked into it, and my file flaskapp.wsgi contains `#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'thismightbewrong'`

Comment: "I have a feeling it has to do with the sha256_crypt.verify() functions" - did you **read** the logs, and see the part where it explicitly **shows you** the `conn.commit()` line of code and points at it with a `^` symbol?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this awhile back and wanted to update the post in case anyone else runs into this.

So all I did was take the `c.execute()` functions out of the `sha256_crpt` IF statement, and put them at the beginning of the function for the page that `login` redirects to. Every user visits the first page so the user session will always have these values.

**As such**:

```
@app.route('/ask/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def ask():
    #clients come here first
    error = ''
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        #grab all the clients info
        email = session['email']
        c.execute("SELECT cid FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
        clientcid = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT phone FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
        phone = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT rating FROM clients WHERE email = (%s)", (thwart(email),))
        rating = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT first_name FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        first_name = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT last_name FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        last_name = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT address FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        address = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT city FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        city = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT state FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        state = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT zip FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        czip = c.fetchone()[0]
        c.execute("SELECT reg_date FROM cpersonals WHERE cid = (%s)", (clientcid,))
        reg_date = c.fetchone()[0]
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        conn.close()


        session['logged_in'] = 'client'
        session['clientcid'] = clientcid
        session['phone'] = phone
        session['rating'] = rating
        session['first_name'] = first_name
        session['last_name'] = last_name
        session['address'] = address
        session['city'] = city
        session['state'] = state
        session['czip'] = czip
        session['reg_date'] = reg_date
```

Comment: If this fixed the problem, it was only by accident, because it gave you the opportunity to fix the `IndentationError` (most likely caused by mixed tabs and spaces to indent) in the original code (which the error message clearly explains, twice at the top, pointing to the exact line).